# Error CoreData swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I am getting an error. I try to type in UserName text field equal to value in database Coredata but it still shows "bad". How can I show "good"?

Anyone please help me:

[image: my code]

[image: coredata]

Comment: What `print(results)` outputs?

Comment: don't link to images of your code, show the code directly in your question

Comment: It prints the username text field when people registered. Now i want when people login, it will check with result, if equal, print good. But my code always print "bad"

Comment: How to show directly, please show me, im new

Comment: @ThànhTrungNguyễn To show the code in the question, select it in Xcode and copy it to the clipboard. Then click on the "edit" link below your questions tags and paste the code into the question. Remember to indent it by 4 spaces.